# electron - loadFile / loadURL takes too much time

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Currently i'm showing a loading (splash) screen before the main window app loads.

it takes roughly 1.2 seconds to completely load (the loading screen) and emit the "ready-to-show" event using this code:

```
   const loadingScreen = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 1400,
      height: 1600,
      minHeight: 800,
      backgroundColor: "#eee",
      minWidth: 1400,
      maxHeight: 1600,
      maxWidth: 1400,
      movable: false,
      icon: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../public/icons/256x256.png"),
      show: false,
      autoHideMenuBar: true,
    });

    loadingScreen.loadFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`);

    loadingScreen.on("ready-to-show", () => {
      loadingScreen?.show();
    });
```

Is there anything to do? I've noticed that discord (electron based app) shows their loading screen 250ms after you click on the icon app.

Comment: is it any faster if you just call `show()` after awaiting the `loadFile` call? Maybe not

Comment: nope, still takes the same time.